# Spring Reactive stream is not working with Netflix Zuul Reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, server-sent-events, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, reactive-streams

We created 7 micro-services for our project and all are exposed through zuul proxy.

One of the micro service(Live-dashboard) contains Spring boot reactive stream for live dashboard refresh using (Server sent events).

The reactive stream is working fine through Live Dashboard micro-service direct rest api (http://localhost:8092/live/dashboard).

But stream is not working through zuul proxy (http://localhost:8091/rest/livedashboard/live/dashboard) it is giving normal api response.

Please give suggestions anyone having any ideas, how reactive stream is working through zuul proxy?

Comment: did you find any solution. I am also stuck with the same problem.

Comment: we are moving to spring cloud gateway instead of zuul. spring cloud gateway supports reactive stream by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `1.x` version of `zuul`, it does not support server sent events. You can find the thread and the response of the contributor [here](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/issues/376#issuecomment-347356803). 
As mentioned in the link, It is supported in `zuul 2.x` versions. So using 2.x versions of zuul might resolve the issue.

Good luck with that.

Comment: yes, we are moving to spring cloud gateway instead of zuul. spring cloud gateway supports reactive stream by default.